# why consumer group showing lag even if there is no data on these partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

Some of the partitions on this particular topic have data and some don't. but consumer group is showing lag on partitions which has no data. what could be the reason for this behavior? I am using kafka version 2.3.0 .

```
GROUP           TOPIC                                        PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET       LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                        HOST            CLIENT-ID

kompressor      bp.ra.v1.alarms                                     5          283             287             4               consumer-28-02c16e5a-03f1-497d-af84-a52081fdc4a7 /172.16.0.55    consumer-28
kompressor      bp.ra.v1.alarms                                     1          24              27              3               consumer-28-02c16e5a-03f1-497d-af84-a52081fdc4a7 /172.16.0.55    consumer-28
kompressor      bp.ra.v1.alarms                                     3          5               7               2               consumer-28-02c16e5a-03f1-497d-af84-a52081fdc4a7 /172.16.0.55    consumer-28
kompressor      bp.ra.v1.alarms                                     36         3               4               1               consumer-29-fea5962b-e4ef-4976-b278-1007fea2700d /172.16.3.70    consumer-29
kompressor      bp.ra.v1.alarms                                     39         117             118             1               consumer-29-fea5962b-e4ef-4976-b278-1007fea2700d /172.16.3.70    consumer-29
kompressor      bp.ra.v1.alarms                                     40         117             121             4               consumer-29-fea5962b-e4ef-4976-b278-1007fea2700d /172.16.3.70    consumer-29
kompressor      bp.ra.v1.alarms                                     35         428             431             3               consumer-29-fea5962b-e4ef-4976-b278-1007fea2700d /172.16.3.70    consumer-29
kompressor      bp.ra.v1.alarms                                     41         137             139             2               consumer-29-fea5962b-e4ef-4976-b278-1007fea2700d /172.16.3.70    consumer-29
kompressor      bp.ra.v1.alarms                                     37         2               3               1               consumer-29-fea5962b-e4ef-4976-b278-1007fea2700d /172.16.3.70    consumer-29
```

Comment: Adding column headings might help. Also you might want to point out which rows you are refering to.

Comment: @Thomas: I have added a column. basically its sixth column ( LAG )

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old question, but one case where I've found this to happen (no data being produced, consumers being 'up-to-date' but still showing lag) is when using e.g. Spring Kafka with `spring.kafka.listener.type: BATCH` or any similar batching consumption in combination with e.g. `spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records > 1`.

In this case, the consumer might be waiting for enough messages to be present to consume a batch and 'waits' otherwise.

The solution would be (at least in the Spring Kafka case) to either set `spring.kafka.listener.type: SINGLE` or set `max-poll-records: 1` (the latter is not recommended with `BATCH` mode since it's rather wasteful).

Answer (score -1):

kafka is basically a cluster of distributed servers. Lag usually occurs when rate of production of data is more than consumption. If there are too many producers and few consumers on the topic, it will also slow down the process.
also it does not matter if any topic has data or not, lag will still be there. This is the small price of distributed system. But if there is a significant lag in consumption than you should try monitoring tools available for kafka to identify the problem.

Comment: Data does matter. If there is no data, then the consumer should have zero lag as it would have to commit the high watermark offset

Comment: @Fakhar Uddin Malik: No one is producing on this topic anymore and the consumer has read everything. still, I see lag here.